# mvc moving using statement from top of razor page to inner web.config is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I tried to remove `@using`statement from top of a mvc razor page

```
 @using Envy.Presentation.Resource.Reports
```

This was working fine for my class in that Folder

```
@ReportRoles.ReportRolesAssignment;
```

However, for "best practices" I figured that I would switch to the inner `web.config` :

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Envy" />
    <add namespace="Envy.Presentation.Resource.Reports"/>
</namespaces>
```

Error:

> The name ReportRoles does not exist in the current context

Why can't I move it to the views `web.config` and get it to recognize, resolve on the razor page?

Comment: did you try closing your views that had the @using statements and reopen them after you added the namespace to your web.config?

Comment: No... Is that important?

Comment: yeah if you make a change to the `Views/Web.confg` you usually have to close your views and reopen them for the change to take effect